# How to simply use manifest?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

How to use manifest in that way so if i go offline and reload page. The images still load. This is my https://jsfiddle.net/h67v5kxf/

and the code 
HTML

```
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1811310904/logo100x100_SM_twitter_400x400.jpg">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1811310904/logo100x100_SM_twitter_400x400.jpg">

<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1811310904/logo100x100_SM_twitter_400x400.jpg">

<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1811310904/logo100x100_SM_twitter_400x400.jpg">
```

and CSS

```
img {
height: 100px;
width:100px;
```

Comment: And your attempt is...?

Comment: The fact you think an "apache file" (which means nothing) has anything to do with it shows that you should probably find a tutorial somewhere.

Comment: Use a service worker

Answer (score 0):

Use a service worker.  Start reading about progressive web apps [here](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)